# How do I create two separate backend pool rules for my ingress.yaml file that has same hostname but different port using AGIC

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I am working with azure gateway ingress controller, I am trying to create two separate backend pool rules for port 8084 and 8083 with the same host name, but when i try to create the backend pool rules only one rule get created which is 8084. But if i change the `- host:  prisma.example.coms` for `port 8084` and keep the host name the same for port 8083  `- host: prisma.example.com` and the  `port 8083`  the backend pool rules get created for both `8083 and 8084`. How do i create two separte rules with the same host name using Azure Gateway Ingress controller for port 8084 and 8083.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"

  name: prismaexample
  namespace: prismaexample
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prisma.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: twistlock-console-example
            port:
              number: 8083

  - host:  prisma.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: twistlock-console-example
            port:
              number: 8084
```

Comment: Ingress resources don't expose port so, you may need to change host name or path on the url. Here is the document about Ingress resource. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

Comment: Controlling the port of the load balancer is typically managed by the controller. In the case, the azure gateway ingress controller. Have you check if AGI controller documentation have this capability? Perhaps adding some annotations....

Comment: @mino yup checked azure documentation thoroughly can't seem to find this capability, but when I use to use nginx ingress controller this was possible but with azure seems that the capability isn't possible.